# Referring to/notifying a user in question body using at (@) sign

Tags: support, comment-replies

When commenting across multiple replies, it's very useful to apply the at sign followed by the nickname of the person that one wishes to reply (or otherwise direct their attention) to. That way, they get a notification that someone's been talking to or in regard of them.

I noticed however that it doesn't work in the question body. I'd like to ask a question based on a comment or reply made in another thread. Posting a comment in the original thread seems vastly off-topic.

Also, sometimes it's useful for pointing out **where** in the referred thread that one can find the interesting part. I can give a link to a question using brackets and parenthesis but if the text mass is vast, I need to explain "*in the reply by this-or-that-user*".

How can I do it more smoothly?

Comment: You cannot refer to users in the body of questions or answers. This is by design. Comments are the only things that are supposed to be directed at individual people.

Comment: @CodyGray Please put that as an answer. I also have a comment but I think it's more organized to post it on the said reply instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to users in the body of questions or answers.

This is by design. Comments are the only things that are supposed to be directed at individual people.

If, when asking a question or posting an answer, you need to refer to an existing post to provide context, you should do so by linking to it. For example:

> In [Cody Gray's answer here] (http://www.example.com/), he says blah blah blah, but I don't understand how that works. I have tried the following…

The user isn't really important, so don't link to their profile, just the post being discussed. And keep in mind that we expect all questions and answers to be completely self-contained and able to stand alone. For instance, it is possible that I delete my original answer. There also shouldn't be a huge research burden placed on readers of your question. As such, you should extract and *summarize* the important details in your own post.

If you are truly asking a follow-up question, and you think it would be appropriate to notify a specific person, you can use an @ reply on one of their posts to do this. It is somewhat off-topic, but it is an acceptable usage of the system, especially if you remember to clean up after yourself and delete your comment once you know that they've seen it. **But please do this sparingly!** Stack Overflow is not a social networking site. There are plenty of other people capable of answering your follow-up question, you don't need to notify me every time! <sup><sub>(Besides, [sometimes we find it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821315/how-to-remove-vertical-divider-in-combobox/23821354#23821354)!)</sub></sup>

**Related:** [Do '@' replies work in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139140/do-replies-work-in-questions-or-answers) and [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: I noticed that you actually point out a specific part of a thread. How do yo do that? I've edited the reply to see the source code of it but the number suffixed to the URL made me no wiser.

Comment: @Konrad Just click the "share" button underneath any post. Copy+paste. Done.

Comment: @CodyGray you know, I keep getting you confused with [Bart](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart).

Comment: @CodyGray This was awkward... I've been using SO for two years now. Never noticed that link. It must be a brand new feature...   ;)